# Google Compute Engine continuously spawning Gunicorn workers, not happening locally

Tags: python, flask, google-compute-engine, gunicorn

I am using gunicorn to run a Flask application.

Below is my app.yaml file, it is exactly the same locally as it is on my Google Computer Engine.

```
runtime: python
runtime_config:
   python_version: 3
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b:$PORT main:app
```

When I run it locally the workers spawn correctly, and also exit correctly if there is a timeout.

```
[2018-11-19 12:25:51 +0000] [23511] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:23514)
[2018-11-19 12:25:51 +0000] [23514] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 23514)
[2018-11-19 12:25:51 +0000] [23519] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 23519
[2018-11-19 12:28:15 +0000] [23511] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:23519)
[2018-11-19 12:28:15 +0000] [23519] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 23519)
[2018-11-19 12:28:15 +0000] [23522] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 23522
```

Where as on the Google Compute Engine it does not exit the worker correctly.

```
2018-11-19 12:28:27 default[20181116t162223]  [2018-11-19 12:28:26 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:7)
2018-11-19 12:28:27 default[20181116t162223]  [2018-11-19 12:28:27 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2018-11-19 12:28:40 default[20181116t162223]  [2018-11-19 12:28:39 +0000] [259] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 259
```

And after, it will then continuously spawn workers, with no timeouts or worker exits.

```
2018-11-19 12:44:50 default[20181116t162223]  [2018-11-19 12:44:50 +0000] [31] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 31
2018-11-19 12:45:01 default[20181116t162223]  [2018-11-19 12:45:01 +0000] [369] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 369
2018-11-19 12:45:05 default[20181116t162223]  [2018-11-19 12:45:05 +0000] [33] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 33
2018-11-19 12:45:15 default[20181116t162223]  [2018-11-19 12:45:15 +0000] [371] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 371
2018-11-19 12:45:16 default[20181116t162223]  [2018-11-19 12:45:16 +0000] [73] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 73
2018-11-19 12:45:18 default[20181116t162223]  [2018-11-19 12:45:18 +0000] [35] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 35
```

Why is my Google Compute Engine spawning gunicorn workers endlessly?